# Nginx / Laravel config to redirect from non index.php route

Tags: laravel, nginx

I've just deployed a newly built website running Laravel 5 and nginx and struggling to setup my nginx config to 301 redirect some old URLs - specifically those with .php extensions.

I'm looking to 301 redirect the below...

```
domain.com/foobar.php?id=123 -> domain.com/foobar/123
```

The default config assumes everything runs from index.php, so Laravel does not trigger on foobar.php.

I have tried adding the following rewrite rule, but it doesn't trigger (I assume because nginx isn't listening out for foobar.php requests?

```
rewrite ^/foobar.php(.*)$ /foobar/$1/ permanent;
```

Relevant snippet of my current nginx config below...

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name domain.com;
root /home/domain.com/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

if ($request_method = GET ) {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: `rewrite` does not *see* the query string. You need a different trick to move the query string to path info. The question has been answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/488444/nginx-rewrite-convert-querystring-to-path

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
rewrite ^/foobar.php /foobar/$arg_id/? permanent;
```

You can get any argument like this `$arg_{your_argument}`. Just replace `{your_argument}` with the actual argument name.